# How to implement CSRF Protection in Zend Framework 3?

Tags: zend-framework3

I need to implement a protection against CSRF attack in Zend Framework 3. I read out the document but unable to figure out on which sections it is described for ZF3, I only able to get it for ZF2. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `CSRF` in form, it's similar as adding any `FORM ELEMENT`. `CSRF` is hidden input.

```
<?php

namespace YOUR_MODULE\Form;


use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element;

class AnimationCategoryForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null, array $options = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);
    }

    public function init()
    {

        $this->add([
            'type' => Element\Csrf::class,
            'name' => 'csrf',
            'options' => [
            'csrf_options' => [
               'timeout' => 600,
            ],
        ],
     ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => Element\Submit::class,
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => [
                'value' => 'Submit',
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Above is the form example. You should also display it in view file.